# Wrong way of using the squeeze rule

Tags: limits, solution-verification, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

[image]

In the first part of the question, I was asked to prove $\lim_{x\to ∞} f(x)={1\over 2}$ using the squeeze rule.
But I did it in a much different way than "Student A" and I fail understand what exactly he did, and where he did wrong.. any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fallacy is that the number of terms is neither constant nor bounded, so a proof by induction on $n$ that $\lim_{x\to c}\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lim_{x\to c}f_i(x)$ doesn't extend in the way Student A hoped. The correct way uses $f(x)=\tfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)}{2x^2}\in\left(\tfrac{x(x-1)}{2x^2},\,\tfrac{x(x+1)}{2x^2}\right]$.

Comment: So are you saying that since he's only calculating the limit for separate parts of the expression, the result is different from if he calculated the limit of the expression as a whole? How do I explain this?

Comment: @MathCurious The same way i did: the number of summed terms is variable, growing as we increase $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the number of terms.
We have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} + \cdots + \frac{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}{x^2} \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} ( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x}),$$
where the number of terms in the parenthesis is $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$.

This is equal to
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{i=\lfloor{x}\rfloor} \frac{1}{x},$$
and the lim cannot go through the sum, since the sum itself is not bounded and depends on $x$. You can still compute the limit and find that it is equal to
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{i=\lfloor{x}\rfloor} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}{x} = 1.
$$

Comment: The sum is bounded by $1$. Also the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! but I'm still having trouble understanding. From what I see, Student A's problem is that he calculated the limit of each part of the equation separately, and then tried to add them up in the final limit but there is no AOL (Algebra of Limits) operation that can support such a thing?